# Where are the fan relays for the 2007 v8 Monte Carlo

Tags: chevrolet, fan, cooling, monte-carlo

I'm looking for the fan relays for a 2007 Monte Carlo V8.  My fans are not turning on. So I need to check the relays to make sure that they are receiving power.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to mechanics.stackexchange.com!  I've edited your post to improve clarity.  Feel free to re-edit if my changes altered your intents.

Answer (score 1):

This should help ... here's where it's located under the hood:

[image: 2007 Monte Carlo Fuse Panel Location]

Here's what the fuse panel layout:

[image: 2007 Monte Carlo Fuse Panel Layout]

Please note there are three relays and two 30A fuses there.